# Racket: does "prefab" structure type give a "to_string" method?

Tags: string, racket

I'm starting coding in the racket programming language.

I would like to know how much prefab brings compared to "transparent". The documentation is not very explicit on this subject. In particular I wanted to know if there is a method to automatically transform a prefab structure into a string. Or do I need to do it myself like this example below :

```lisp
#lang racket

(struct tx (sender receiver value) #:prefab)

(define (tx->string tx)
  (string-append (tx-sender tx) (tx-receiver tx) (number->string (tx-value tx))))
```

Comment: The JSON part of this should be a separate question, and you should mention which JSON package you're using - there's a few available for Racket.

Comment: Ok @Shawn I edited my question to remove the JSON part and created a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75625639/racket-does-prefab-structure-type-allow-for-automatic-json-serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefab structures automatically define a printer that creates output that can be `read` back in if written out with `write` (Assuming all the values held in the struct's fields can be too), and there are functions like [`~s`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._%7E7es%29%29) and [`format`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._format%29%29) that use `write` to create strings from values.

For example:

```lisp
Welcome to Racket v8.8 [cs].
> (struct tx (sender receiver value) #:prefab)
> (define my-tx-struct (tx 1 2 3))
> my-tx-struct ; The REPL uses print, not write
'#s(tx 1 2 3)
> (~s my-tx-struct)
"#s(tx 1 2 3)"
> (call-with-input-string (~s my-tx-struct) read)
'#s(tx 1 2 3)
```

Transparent structs have a printer that outputs forms that call the struct constructor with `print`, and a vector that describes the struct with `write`:

```lisp
> (struct tx (sender receiver value) #:transparent)
> (define my-tx-struct (tx 1 2 3))
> my-tx-struct
(tx 1 2 3)
> (~s my-tx-struct)
"#(struct:tx 1 2 3)"
> (call-with-input-string (~s my-tx-struct) read)
'#(struct:tx 1 2 3)
> (vector? (call-with-input-string (~s my-tx-struct) read))
#t
```

Comment: There is no difference between prefab and transparent struct in this regard ?

Comment: @MohamedLEGH `print`, `write` and `display` format them differently.

Comment: ([Documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/printing.html#%28part._print-structure%29) on structure printing.)