# Racket: does "prefab" structure type allow for automatic JSON serialization?

Tags: json, serialization, racket

I have a question about JSON serialization and prefab struct. Is it possible to automatically serialize a prefab struct into a JSON or do I need to do it myself ?

For example for this example below, what is the best way to transform it into a JSON ?

```lisp
#lang racket

(struct tx (sender receiver value) #:prefab)
```

Comment: You'd have to write your own routine (preferably by returning something the base json module (or whatever) accepts as a jsexpr so it can write out the actual json text)

Comment: If you use non-prefab structures, I was inspired to write a generic method for them for converting to jsexprs. Can elaborate if wanted.

Comment: Yes @Shawn even if I can come up with a solution myself, I'm interested to see your method